# Sort array, but ignore some specific characters in the beginning

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with all elements being strings. And I want to sort them alphabetically, so I know that I should use the `sort()` function. But what I want to happen is that it will ignore the first few characters based on what they are.

For example, if there is an array `['<FILE> dogs', '<DIR> more', '<FILE> cats']`, how will I make it ignore the text <FILE> and , and sort these strings by the text that comes after them? Do I have to create a custom sorting function?

Comment: *Do I have to create a custom sorting function?* Yes :-)

Comment: bcasically, only the comparator you have to create and not a entire function to sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could strip the tags, like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822464/1447675), and take the rest string as sortable result.

```js
var array =  ['<FILE> dogs', '<DIR> more', '<FILE> cats'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getRaw(s) {
        return s.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').trim();
    }

    return getRaw(a).localeCompare(getRaw(b));
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Both the `(?:` and the `m` flag are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

To solve an issue like this, I will advise you to create an empty array then loop through the incoming array , replace any string that matches `<FILE>, <DIR>` with empty string and push to the empty array after which you'll apply your sort function on the new array.

Comment: But he wants to sort the **original** array based on a sort order determined by removing the initial characters.

Comment: That should solve his issue if he won't be needing the ```<DIR> ```

Comment: But he **does** need the `<DIR>` in the output. He simply does not want to include it in the sorting rule.

Comment: Oh, I understand!

Answer (score 0):

A very simplistic approach could be;

```js
var sorted =  ['<FILE> dogs', '<DIR> more', '<FILE> cats'].sort((a,b) => a.split(/>\s*/)[1].localeCompare(b.split(/>\s*/)[1]));
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own sort-function, like below. In this function, you can use regex-patterns or whatever to sort the array however you like. The snippet below sorts the array, but ignores the first character whenever this is an 'a'.

```js
var arr = ["aa", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bb", "bc" ];

var removeFirstA = function (str) {
  return str[0] === "a" ? str.substr(1) : str;
};

arr.sort(function (obj1, obj2) {
  return removeFirstA(obj1).localeCompare(removeFirstA(obj2));
});

document.body.innerHTML = arr;
```

Comment: Comparator functions need to return -1, 0, or +1.

Comment: @torazaburo It doesn't have to, otherwise the snippet wouldn't give the expected result. But for the sake of a 'good practice answer' I've changed it.

Comment: Yes, it does have to. Otherwise, sorting will exhibit unpredictable behavior in certain cases, and behavior could differ between engines.

Comment: I do agree on the unpredictable behaviour part, however returning 0 still has different behavior between different engines. Returning any other number is perfectly fine: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Well, unfortunately that's just wrong. Returning zero is the desired/specified behavior when the two items are to be considered equal for sorting purposes. If an engine does not handle that correctly, then it is a bug.